# Determine screen coordinates from point in DirectX world

Tags: c#, slimdx

I have a point in space represented by a 4x4 matrix. I'd like to get the screen coordinates for the point.  Picking appears to be the exact opposite fo what I need. I'm using the screen coordinate to determine where to draw text.

Currently the text I draw is floating in space far in front of the points. I've attached a screenshot of zoomed-in and zoomed-out to better explain.  As you can see in the screenshot, the distance between each point is the same when zoomed in, when it should be smaller.

[image]
[image]

Am I missing a transformation?  World coordinates consider 0,0,0 to be the center of the grid.  I'm using SlimDX.

```
var viewProj = mMainCamera.View * mMainCamera.Projection;

//Convert 4x4 matrix for point to Vector4
var originalXyz = Vector3.Transform(Vector3.Zero, matrix);

//Vector4 to Vector3
Vector3 worldSpaceCoordinates = new Vector3(originalXyz.X, originalXyz.Y, originalXyz.Z);

//Transform point by view projection matrix
var transformedCoords = Vector3.Transform(worldSpaceCoordinates, viewProj);

Vector3 clipSpaceCoordinates = new Vector3(transformedCoords.X, transformedCoords.Y, transformedCoords.Z);
Vector2 pixelPosition = new Vector2((float)(0.5 * (clipSpaceCoordinates.X + 1) * ActualWidth),  (float)(0.5 * (clipSpaceCoordinates.Y + 1) * ActualHeight));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was way overthinking this. Just project the point to the screen by passing Vector3.Project your viewport information. It's a 3 line solution.

```
var viewProj = mMainCamera.View * mMainCamera.Projection;
var vp = mDevice.ImmediateContext.Rasterizer.GetViewports()[0];
var screenCoords = Vector3.Project(worldSpaceCoordinates, vp.X, vp.Y, vp.Width, vp.Height, vp.MinZ, vp.MaxZ, viewProj);
```